# jQuery code not working on react page after coming back from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I've written a jQuery code that adds and removes css classes from the accordion based on some condition. It works fine the fist time it loads but when I click on any links on the page and go to another page from there, it doesn't work when I come back to the same page.

Is it jQuery or React?
Here's my jQuery code.

```
$(function(){
    $(".accordion").on("click", ".accordion-header", function(e){
        if(!$(this).hasClass("has-add-bg")){
            $(".accordion-item").removeClass("add-bg");
            $(".accordion-header").removeClass("has-add-bg");
            $(this).addClass("has-add-bg");
            $(this).parent().addClass("add-bg");
        }else{
            $(this).parent().removeClass("add-bg");
            $(this).removeClass("has-add-bg");
            $(".accordion-item").removeClass("add-bg");
        }
    })
})
```

I tried using state but the problem is I want to add or remove the class of only the accordion I've clicked on. Not sure how to achieve that result just with state so wrote jQuery.

Comment: You really shouldn't be mixing jQuery with other frameworks (React, Angular, etc.) as they have their own internal ways of maintaining and updating the DOM as necessary that do not play nicely with jQuery (and even vanilla JavaScript) DOM manipulation.

Comment: Can you please suggest any other way around?

Comment: You can use the react state to set a condition in the onClick and then according to the state set conditional classNames on the elements in the return. 
check out the classnames library for example https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames